# Trying to open programs with bat file but always comes back invalid

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am a streamer and I need a few programs to stream. It's annoying to open all of them so I tried putting them in a batch file. I looked up the process and followed it,but every time I run the batch file it comes back invalid.

This is what my batch file looks like:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files "(x86)\obs-studio\bin\64bit"
start obs64.exe

@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\HexChat"
start hexchat.exe

@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nightbot"
start nightbot.exe

exit
```

Cmd gives me an error saying it cannot find the file. When I put this into cmd by itself it opens the program.

Also is there a way to add applications from chrome to the file?

Comment: `cd C:\Program Files "(x86)\obs-studio\bin\64bit"` isn't valid. Use `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\obs-studio\bin\64bit"` instead (note the position of the first quote).

Comment: Also, just stylistically, you only need the first `@echo off`.

Comment: While debugging, you should not have ANY `@echo off`.  Removing those lines would let you see the errors that CMD is issuing, and you wouldn't have to come to StackOverflow for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a command prompt window and run from within this window `start /?` which outputs the help for this command and explaining all options.

Following batch file most likely works:

```
@echo off
start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\obs-studio\bin\64bit\obs64.exe"
start "" "%ProgramFiles%\HexChat\hexchat.exe"
start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Nightbot\nightbot.exe"
```

This batch file starts the three applications with current directory on execution of the batch file being also the current directory for the 3 started applications.

But the following batch file should be used if it is really necessary that each application is started with the application's directory as current directory:

```
@echo off
start "" /D"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\obs-studio\bin\64bit" obs64.exe
start "" /D"%ProgramFiles%\HexChat" hexchat.exe
start "" /D"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Nightbot" nightbot.exe
```

With parameter `/D` and path of application's folder the **Start In** directory is set first like when using command **CD**. So for example `hexchat.exe` is started with current directory being `C:\Program Files\HexChat` for this application.

The two double quotes after command **START** are necessary as this command interprets first double quoted string as title for the process. By using `""` an empty title string is explicitly specified resulting in rest of command line being correct interpreted as expected. I suppose those three applications are all GUI applications and not console applications and therefore a real title string being useful on running a console application in an new command process for the console window is not really necessary.

`%ProgramFiles%` references the predefined environment variable *ProgramFiles* containing path to standard program files folder for 64-bit applications on 64-bit Windows when batch file is started with 64-bit `cmd.exe` as default on 64-bit Windows and is replaced by Windows command interpreter before execution of the command line on your Windows computer by `C:\Program Files`.

`%ProgramFiles(x86)%` references the predefined environment variable *ProgramFiles(x86)* containing always path to standard program files folder for 32-bit applications on 64-bit Windows and is replaced by Windows command interpreter before execution of the command line on your Windows computer by `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

It is of course also possible to use the real paths in your computer instead of the environment variable references if this batch file is never shared with other people.

Extra hint:
Run in a command prompt window the command you want to use with `/?` as parameter to get displayed the help for this command. Other sources for help on commands and predefined environment variables displayed all on running in a command prompt window `set` are:

- [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Microsoft's command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands)
- [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) and [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details)